# Library which converts HTML to pdf,doc and xls

Tags: php

is there a php library which converts the html content into pdf, word docuement and excel file.
I have already tried with tcpdf library, phpword, phpexcel but using different library

Comment: Please see other questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593870/how-to-create-a-pdf-file-from-an-html-using-php-and-then-save-it-on-the-server

Comment: You can try `phpexcel library` on http://phpexcel.codeplex.com See this http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Features&referringTitle=Documents

Comment: There is no single library that will convert to all those formats: PHPExcel can write both Excel (BIFF and OfficeOpenXML) and PDF, while PHPWord can write both Word (OfficeOpenXML) and PDF. Both require an additional 3rd party library for PDF rendering. But if you've already tried these, how do they fail to meet your requirements? And what exactly do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
 http://html2pdf.fr/en/default

```
$html = file_get_contents("valid.html");
require_once("html2pdf.class.php");
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF("P", "A4", "en", array(10, 10, 10, 10));
$html2pdf->setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$html2pdf->Output("pdf/PDF.pdf", "F"); //output to file
$html2pdf->Output(); //output to browser
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a library called [Php KoolGrid](http://demo.koolphp.net/Examples/KoolGrid/Exporting/Excel_Word_CSV_PDF/index.php), But it seems, it just exports the html table only. It has some methods to export like,

```
• PHP::GridTableView::ExportToExcel()
• PHP::GridTableView::ExportToWord()
• PHP::GridTableView::ExportToCSV()
• PHP::GridTableView::ExportToPDF()
• PHP::ExportSettings::IgnorePaging
• PHP::ExportSettings::FileName
```